# "nächsten Monat" vs. "nächster Monat"

Tags: grammatical-case, time

I know that the accusative case is used in time expressions, for example:

> Mein Urlaub beginnt nächsten Monat.

What I'm confused about is the following sentence:

> Das Ablaufdatum für deinen Ausweis ist nächsten Monat - du solltest ihn ersetzen.

Can I use "nächster Monat" here? Shouldn't "sein" take the nominative case in both the subject & the copula?

Answer (score 1):

It's fine.

> Das Ablaufdatum für deinen Ausweis ist nächsten Monat - du solltest ihn ersetzen.

Note that "nächsten Monat" simply specifies where the expiration date lies in time. "nächsten Monat" is a "Umstandsergänzung der Zeit" (adverbial phrase) here. This makes sense since the expiration date is some day within the next month.

It's same as in this sentence, for example:

> Das Geburtstagsfest ist nächsten Monat.

You could say:

> Das Ablaufdatum für deinen Ausweis ist der nächste Monat - du solltest ihn ersetzen.

but this implies that the ID really expires at the beginning of the month. I would almost expect the ID to say something like "Ablaufdatum: August 2022" in this case, which in my experience is uncommon.

Comment: This advice shows up a couple times on this site, but is not really helpful for non-native speakers: >>Consider that if you ask "Wann ist das Ablaufdatum?" the answer is "nächsten Monat"<<

Comment: @infinitezero Yes, you're right here. OP wouldn't have asked if they knew the answer to that question. But theses questions can make sense in some instances, especially with cases.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what *Ablaufdatum* refers to. If it refers to any day *within* the next month (e.g., *Ablaufdatum: 17.08.2022*), then it should in fact be

> Das Ablaufdatum für deinen Ausweis ist *(im) nächsten Monat* – du solltest ihn ersetzen.

If, however, the *Ablaufdatum* explicitly refers to the month itself (e.g., *Ablaufdatum: August 2022*), then we have the so-called *Gleichsetzungsnominative* (I don't know whether *equative nominative* is the term used in English):

> Das Ablaufdatum für deinen Ausweis ist *nächster Monat* – du solltest ihn ersetzen.

Here, [*nächster*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:nah#Superlativ) is used without a definite article and is thus declined strongly. If a definite article is used, the weakly declined form [*nächste*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:nah#Superlativ) is chosen:

> Das Ablaufdatum für deinen Ausweis ist *der nächste Monat* – du solltest ihn ersetzen.

Comment: I disagree about *nächsten Monat* being Dative - it only makes sense with *im*, and a preposition is almost never omitted in German. Compare the analogous *Mein Urlaub beginnt nächste Woche* - there is no way this can be Dative.